# What is the best way to iterate and process an entire table from database?

Tags: java, postgresql, language-agnostic

I have a table called Token in my database that represents texts tokenized.

Each row haves attributes like textblock, sentence and position(for identifying the text that the token is from) and logical fields like text, category, chartype, etc.

What I want to know is iterate over all tokens to find patterns and do some operations. For example, merging two adjacent tokens that have the category as Name into one (and after this, reset the positions). I think that I will need some kind of list

What is the best way to do this? With SQL queries to find the patterns or iterating over all tokens in the table. I think the queries will be complex a lot and maybe, iterating as a list will be more simple, but I don't know which is the way (as example, retrieving to a Java list or using a language that I can iterate and do changes right on database).

To this question not be closed, what I want to know is what the most recommended way to do this? I'm using Java, but if other language is better, no problem, I think I will need use R to do some statistic calculus.

**Edit:** The table is large, millions rows, load entire in memory is not possible.

Comment: [off topic] please don't open too many new questions. Though your field of research is interesting (to some of us), people might get confused or even annoyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an engineering decision to be made, based mostly on the size of the corpus you want to maintain, and the kind of operations you want to perform on them.

If the size gets bigger than "what fits in the editor", you'll need some kind of database. That may or may not be an SQL database. But there is also the code part: if you want perform non-trivial operations on the data, you might need a *real* programming language (could be anything: C, Java, Python. anything goes). In that case, the communication with the database will become a bottleneck: you need to generate queries that produce results that fit in the application programme's memory. SQL is powerful enough to represent and store N-grams and do some calculations on them, but that is about as far as you are going to get. In any case the database has to be fully normalised, and that will cause it to be more difficult to understand for non-DBAs.

My own toy project, http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ used a hybrid approach:

- the data was obtained by a python crawler
- the corpus was stored as-is in the database
- the actual (modified MegaHal) Markov code stores it's own version of the corpus in a (binary) flatfile, containing the dictionary, N-grams, and the associated coefficients.
- the training and text generation is done by a highly optimised C program
- the output was picked up by another python script, and submitted to the target.

[in another life, I would probably have done some more normalisation, and stored N-grams or trees in the database. That would possibly cause the performance to drop to only a few generated sentences per second. It now is about 4000/sec]

My gut feeling is that what you want is more like a "linguistic workbench" than a program that does exactly one task efficiently (like wakkerbot). In any case you'll need to normalise a bit more: store the tokens as {tokennumber,tokentext} and refer to them only by number. Basically, a text is just a table (or array) containing a bunch of token numbers. An N-gram is just a couple of tokennumbers+the corresponding coefficients.

Comment: Your first paragraph is a perfect argument for doing it in a real language IN the database.  PostgreSQL supports literally dozens of common and obscure procedural languages, and if you don't want to learn a new one it's likely got one you already know, like perl, python, C, sql, plsql, R (a statistics program similar to S), java, and many more.

Comment: I beg to differ. For general purpose use (like the OP), a database is a must have. It makes data management easier. For narrow-scale applications, dedicated optimisations will force you out of the database. (remember: Google 1.0 needed the dictionary to be loaded in core. For obvious reasons) Later developments forced Google to invent GFS, and other pre-nosql stuff. Regarding script languages: python's dictionaries are too fat for this kind of application, one of my co-developers tried it, and (thow is was more elegant) it just did not deliver. But it all depends on the "narrowness" of the

Comment: .. application at hand. The "locality of reference" of the code is also a factor. (that is not a factor in DBMS land, we'd prefer to talk in terms of disk-footprint, or number of pagefetches needed)

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a small table, or proving out a merge strategy, then just setup a query that finds all of the candidate duplicate lines and dump the relevant columns out to a table. Then view that table in a text editor or spreadsheet to see if your hypothesis about the duplication is correct.

Keep in mind that any time you try to merge two rows into one, you will be deleting data. Worst case is that you might merge ALL of your rows into one. Proceed with caution!

Comment: Yeah, when testing, run all your queries in a transaction and view the intermediate state, and have backups...  It's easy to make a play database in pgsql, just:

create database newdb with template olddb;

tada a disposable database to play with.  Note: Could take a while since it's gotta copy a whole db.  Still quicker than dumping and restoring a new db.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most optimized method but it's a design that allows you to write the code easily.

1. write an entity class that represent a row in your table.
2. write a factory method that allows you to get the entity object of a given row id, i.e. a method that create an object of entity class witht the values from the specified row.
3. write methods that remove and insert a given row object into table.
4. write a row counting method.
5. now, you can try to iterate your table using your java code. remember that if you merge between two row, you need to correctly adjust the next index.

This method allows you use small memory but you will be using a lot of query to create the row.

The concept is very similar or identical to ORM (Object Relational Mapping). If you know how tho use hibernate or other ORM then try those libraries.

Comment: If the index is maintaining the indexes, you don't have to update or reindex them, it's automatic.  As mentioned previously, jdbc should be able to go into some kind of "use cursors automatically" mode for you so then you're not holding it all in memory at once.

Comment: That should be "If the database is maintaining the indexes"

Comment: I wasn't talking about the index in the databse. I was talking about the index in the loop within the program. They can be different and usually you don't want to update the indexes of the twhole table.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it'd be easier, and likely faster overall, to load everything into Java and do your operations there to avoid continually re-querying the DB.

There are some pretty strong numerical libs for Java and statistics, too; I wouldn't dismiss it out-of-hand until you're sure what you need isn't available (or is too slow).

Comment: I forgot to said that I cannot load the entire table in memory, but I think I can use a cursor for this.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição Ah, okay :) In that case, I'm not as sure what the best approach would be

Comment: The cursor is the best way.  Be sure to declare it with the update keyword so you can then change the values in the master table.  Dave, loading the whole data set into java is not scalable.  I've spent the last year chasing down and fixing that problem because of what a developer did in the early stages of the application I worked on.  Nightmare to deal with.  If you need stats in pgsql, use plr, it'll kick Java hard performance wise doing statistics and it's built for just doing statistics.  Quite impressive really.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Obviously it's not scalable, but w/o any info regarding the dataset, there's no way to know if it *needs* to be.

Comment: That's why you default to a simple method that's scalable first.  And then move to something much faster and optimized if analysis shows the data set will be small enough to toss into memory each time.  If you're not sure, and you're doing statistical analysis on even moderately large datasets, you can get a really bad surprise when your app starts exploding when you get to handful or more of users.

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of jdbc connectors toss a cursor on everything you do, so at least you don't have to worry about exhausting a db server's memory to hold the result set.  App server maybe.  But you're right that some things don't need to scale, like a workgroup app for 10 people in a small office.  Unless they're processing stats on a huge dataset they likely won't see any difference.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Sure, if you assume a particular class of application, which this application isn't. There are lots of bounded sets kept in DBs. We don't disagree in principle; stop trying to convince me. Different apps lead to different assumptions regarding scalability, and different solution sets.

Comment: I was pretty sure I was agreeing with you...  Don't assume an argumentative tone from me please.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're designing a text search engine.  You should first see if pgsql's full text search engine is right for you.

If you do it without full text search, loading pl into pgsql and learning to drive it is likely to be the fastest and most efficient solution.  It'll allow you to put all this work into a few well thought out lines of R, and do it all in the db where access to the data is closest.  the only time to avoid such a plan is when it would make the database server work VERY hard, like holding the dataset in memory and cranking a single cpu core across it.  Then it's ok to do it app side.

Whether you use pl/R or not, access large data sets in a cursor, it's by far the most efficient way to get either single or smaller subsets of rows.  If you do it with a select with a where clause for each thing you want to process then you don't have to hold all those rows in memory at once.  You can grab and discard parts of result sets while doing things like running averages etc.

Think about scale here.  If you had a 5 TB database, how would you access it to do this the fastest?  A poor scaling solution will come back to bite you even if it's only accessing 1% of the data set.  And if you're already starting on a pretty big dataset today, it'll just get worse with time.

pl/R http://www.joeconway.com/plr/

Comment: I think his field is more like computer linguistics. Your example of a 5 TB database and expecting to retrieve (and I hope: aggregate) 1% of the rows is valid. But this query needs to be executed multiple times, every time with (almost) 1 % different selection of objects. Language research is very related to DNA research. Both in volume as in methods. Genome research currently uses hybrid/flatfile methods, too. Search engines and BI are a bit different, because the typical usage is narrow enough to allow distributed and incremental methods.